# Unable to access user's profile from Google Plus

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus, scribe

I am using Scribe-Java to connect to Google plus using OAuth2. I am able to authenticate my application and obtain user's permission, but when I try to access anything other than `userinfo`, I am getting this Exception.

> 403
>
> {
>
> "error": {
>
> ```
>   "errors": [
>             {
>
>           "domain": "usageLimits",
>            "reason": "accessNotConfigured","message": "Access Not Configured"
>
>             }
>
>             ],
>
>   "code": 403,
>
> "message": "Access Not Configured"
>
>      }
>
> }
> ```

I have set the scope of my application as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` and to access user's profile I am using this url:

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userid}/activities/public`

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there some other scope that I need to use here to access the Profile?

Comment: Could you set Scribe's `debug` mode on? Also, a `403` response usually means that you're not allowed to perform that action, regardless of authorization issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Visit the Google APIs console:
http://code.google.com/apis/console

2) Go to the 'Services' page.

3) Enable the Google+ API by switching it to On

Comment: Can you explain how exactly it will help? I am able to get userinfo even without switching the google+ api to on.

Comment: It should eliminate the 403 accessNotConfigured error.  This is not necessary for the userinfo endpoint as it is used for other purposes (like OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0 authentication).  Note that the Google+ API documentation states that you should "Activate the Google+ API in the Services pane of the Google APIs Console."  More info here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#about

Comment: Worked for me when I switched on the corresponding API in admin console. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in PHP using [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/):

I had to activate the following in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) in *APIs & Auth* -> *APIs*

- Contacts API
- Google+ API

See also the discussion at http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Google.html